# Angular Js - Test POST request that returns an object with Jasmine

Tags: ajax, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a service set up which makes all my AJAX calls. I want to test my login method, which sends an AJAX POST `$http.post` to a particular URL, which returns an objects with the result (login passed or failed). This result is an object. I have not return the code exactly to test the service, but I'm trying to test the URL first. This is how it looks right now:

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: Ajax', function () {

    var service, httpBackend;

    // load the service's module
    beforeEach(module('mySampleApp'));

    // instantiate service
    beforeEach(inject(function (Ajax, _$httpBackend_) {
        httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        service = Ajax;
    }));

    it('Test AJAX call', function () {
        httpBackend.expect('POST', 'http://myloginurl', {u: 'xyz', p: 'pass'}, { withCredentials: true})
        .respond(201, 'success');
    });
});
```

This passes. Now I tried putting a wrong URL, wrong username/password, but it still passes! How do I test this?

UPDATE:
Better written now:

```
//Ajax is my AJAX service
it('should test the login AJAX call', inject(function (Ajax) {
    httpBackend.expect('POST', 'http://myloginurl')
        .respond(200, "[{ status: 200, //some more data }]");
    httpBackend.flush();
    Ajax.authenticate({u: 'xyz', password: 'pass' })
        .then(function(data){
            expect(data.status).toBe(200);
        });
}));
```

I get this:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux) Service: Ajax should test the login AJAX call FAILED
Error: No pending request to flush !
blah blah...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a

```
httpBackend.flush();
```

in that will throw an exception if the expected url wasn't called - thereby failing your test.

Also, I can't see that you're calling the code that does the Ajax request anywhere - you need to do that before calling flush().

So something like:

```
it('Test AJAX call', function () {
        httpBackend.expect('POST', 'http://myloginurl', {u: 'xyz', p: 'pass'}, { withCredentials: true})
        .respond(201, 'success');
        service.functionThatMakesCallToServer();
        httpBackend.flush();
});
```

If functionThatMakesCallToServer() calls the url in the httpBackend.expect(...) line, everything will be ok. If it doesn't httpBackend.flush() will throw an error as a call that was expected did not happen. The error will cause your test to fail.

Comment: I'm updating my question and adding the response I get. Please check it!

Comment: Also, `httpBackend.expect(...)` does the AJAX call right?

Comment: No, httpBackend.expect(...) does not do the call - it tells httpBackend to expect a call. httpBackend.flush() then processes all calls. Somewhere in between those two things you need to call your function that does the ajax request.

Comment: How do I add it? Sorry, I'm a noob, trying to get my head around testing `post` AJAX calls!

Comment: Ohh, so I need to include the service that actually makes the call? Thanks! What about the returned data, how do I check it?

Comment: You have setup the request to respond with the string 'success' - (BTW - usually this would be an object). Presumably your service does something useful with this response that you can test for with an expect(...).toBe(...) line. You have to di this after flush().

Comment: My actual endpoint responds with an object. Let me please try this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62113/discussion-between-rutwick-gangurde-and-fordio).